# Laravel Eloquent 3 Table Join Query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 migration

Default User migration, Event migration and Share migration.

```
Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('owner');
        $table->dateTime('start_date');
        $table->dateTime('end_date');
        $table->dateTime('alert_date');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('local');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('owner')->references('id')->on('users');
    });

Schema::create('shares', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('host');
        $table->unsignedInteger('guest');
        $table->boolean('host_answer')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('guest_answer')->nullable();;
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('host')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('guest')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

Then i have the relationships established on the respective models.

Users:

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Event::class);
}

public function host()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Share::class);
}

public function guest()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Share::class);
}
```

Event:

```
public function userOwner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'owner');
}
```

Share:

```
public function userGuest()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'guest');
}
```

I need all distinct events where at least one of 3 conditions are meet:

1- events.owner = $someUserId.

2- shares.host  = $someUserId and shares.guest_answer = 1.

3- shares.guest = $someUserId and shares.guest_answer = 1.

If this was simply SQL i guess i would be able to make the query... but is laravel so i'm having some troubles with my query.

This is what i get:

```
 $events = Event::join('users', 'events.owner', '=', 'users.id')
                ->join('shares', 'users.id', '=', 'shares.host')
                ->where  ([[ 'events.owner', $userId ]])
                ->orWhere([[ 'shares.host', $userId],
                           [ 'shares.guest_answer', '1' ]])
                ->orWhere([[ 'shares.guest', $userId],
                           [ 'shares.guest_answer', '1' ]])
                ->paginate(10);
```

But this query is simply returning the events where events.owner = $userId.

Thank you very much for you time.

Comment: Is there any connection between the Events and Shares apart from the user?
It is needed a relation between the Share and Event for the second and third condition to have any effect on the Events result set.

Comment: It's not possible relating Events and Shares directly, so i'm using users to do the job. I already notice what was the problem. It was multiple join on the same table. You can see the solution i found. It's working just perfectly.  Thank you :)

Comment: Unless they are related by any other mean then the query, whatever mean you use, will always yield results filtered by the condition 1 first and then one of the others and not by at least one condition. Is that what you need?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply mate. The code bellow is working just fine. Is doing exactly what i need. It will join all the 3 table based on the users table. So User has many events and user has many shares. Its an easy join. And then it will check for the 3 conditions. It can meet 0, 1, 2 or all the 3 conditions...

Answer (score 0):

```
    $userId = Auth::id();

    $events = Event::join('users'       , 'events.owner', '=', 'users.id')
                   ->join('shares as sg', 'users.id'    , '=', 'sg.guest')
                   ->join('shares as sh', 'users.id'    , '=', 'sh.host' )

                   ->Where([   ['events.owner'    , '=', $userId] ])

                   ->orWhere([ ['sg.host'         , '=', $userId] ,
                               ['sg.guest_answer' , '=', '1']     ])

                   ->orWhere([ ['sh.guest'        , '=', $userId] ,
                               ['sh.guest_answer' , '=', '1']     ])

                    ->paginate(10);
```